# Python script to communicate with router

Tags: python-3.x, router

Is there a way to create script that will modify router settings if there is only 1 url? The interface of control panel is made of html and javascript and whatever I click its always http://192.168.1.1/ site. Already tried to record actions through selenium IDE, but didn´t got a clue how to implement it in my .py script. What module, order should be used?

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness ... it that because the page uses frames?

Comment: Not sure about that frames. It is pretty old device though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture your browser network logs when you change setting on the router and emulate it using python requests package to build a payload and trigger an action.

To do that, open the router page in your browser and open the developer tools network tab, then do something on the page while saving the communication you see in the network tab.